# php/sql query works locally but does not work on server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wampserver

i am using the following update query to update my code. it works fine on local server but not working on live server, can some one kindly tell me what may be the reason

```
<?php
        if (isset($_POST['submitContactInfo'])) {
            $socityId = $_SESSION['socityid'];
            $city = $_POST['city'];
            $pin = $_POST['pin'];
            $state = $_POST['state'];
            $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
            $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $address = $_POST['address'];


            $sql = "UPDATE `_acappv1`.`society_profile` SET `ADDR` = '$address', `CITY` = '$city', `PIN` = '$pin', `STATE` = '$state', `TEL` = '$telephone', `MOBILE` = '$mobile', `EMAIL` = '$email' WHERE `society_profile`.`SOCIETY_ID` = '$socityId'; ";

            $res = mysql_query($sql);
        }
        ?>
```

One thing i noticed as when i click on submit button, on serverside the page refreshed, while on client side page does not refresh and adds the data.

Comment: What doesn't work? What error message do you get? What troubleshooting have you done?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: try to put this: mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

Comment: @JohnConde table is not updating when i try to update it using update form.

Comment: You should try to see what MySQL thinks is going on. Try to see if there was an error and what it was with mysql_error.

Comment: are you sure the database `_acappv1` exists on live server?

Comment: http://82.157.70.109/mirrorbooks/php5/067232511X/ch10lev1sec1.html

Comment: Is `$_SESSION['socityid']` a typo (should be `$_SESSION['societyid']`)?

Comment: try concatenating strings.. Ex: "...SET `ADDR` = '".$address."'..."

Comment: @MichaelTichoň die does not return any thing,

Comment: @MichaelTichoň got this "UPDATE command denied to user 'roseblac'@'localhost' for table 'society_profile'"

Comment: That error tells you all you need to know. Grant `UPDATE` privilege to the `roseblac` user. And listen to @JohnConde: *don't use `mysql_*` statements!!*

Comment: @JulianH.Lam  thanks alot, and i got this code a few days back so there are alot of queries with mysql, so thats why i am stick to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much to all of you, i got my issue solved by making a small change to mysql query, by removing the `_acappv1`. (database name), and it start working.